# Best data structure for tic-tac-toe game with infinite board

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suppose I am designing a game of tic-tac-toe game playing in an infinite board. The player who succeeds in placing three of their marks in a horizontal, vertical, or diagonal row wins.
 What is the best data structure to represent it?
I can only think of hash table to record positions. For each new position, check its surroundings are checked to evaluate a win.

Any other better idea?

Comment: You're probably looking for some kind of [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix). There are many different ways to implement such a thing. The "best" for your application will depend on your requirements: ease of implementation? Maximize speed? Minimize space? Only you can decide what best means for you.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have an infinite board, you should still allocate coordinate for your game. The coordinate could be something like from 0 to a a very large number.

Now, you have a practically infinite coordinate. Why not a simple dictionary of coordinates? C++:

```
std::map<std::pair<long, long>, MySquare> m;
```

For example, you are on (460,670), you would like to check (461,671). Simply check if (461,671) is in `m`, if not you add a new entry.

This very simple design is robust  as it allocates memory only if you really need it.

Don't overcomplicate yourself.